# IIS web deploy - temp page when publishing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, webdeploy

i have searched on google without succses. I whis to display a custom page when i publish my website on iis 7. I know about the Offline.html or something like this. But i whant the process to be automatic on publish. Display a page like : we are upgrading the website, it will be avaliable in a minute.
Now when i publish my mvc site, it can take up to 3 minutes, it only display an error.

Tanks.
Ps: sorry for my bad english, it's not my first language.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio? AFAIK Visual Studio still produces the *App_offline.htm* file for Visual Studio 2012/3.

Comment: im using visual studio 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a file called app_offline.htm in the root of your site. If this file exists then its contents will be displayed instead of your site. You can then deploy your site, and then just delete or rename the app_offline.htm file when you are done.

Comment: If you want to automate all of this, take a look at [this](http://sedodream.com/2012/01/08/howtotakeyourwebappofflineduringpublishing.aspx).

Comment: i like how it's make, i test it then mark your answer.

Comment: I can't get it to work, it said msdeploy exit with error -1 ...
I don't know if this is compatible with VS 2013 ...

Comment: i have found that vs2013 and MSDeploy 3.0 and up support EnableMSDeployAppOffline, by adding "<EnableMSDeployAppOffline>true</EnableMSDeployAppOffline>" in the pubxml of the publish profile ... but i can't see how to personalize the html... and my test show than it's not effective at the start of the publish, it take some time ... so user can get the "Runtime Error". wish is what i want to prevent. Notice the user the app is updating or something like that.